# Como usar função WHERE em coluna criada a partir de uma formula?

Tags: mysql

Escrevi esse código:

```
SELECT produtos.id AS id, 
nome_produto AS Nome, 
SUM(estoque.Estoque_produto) AS Estoque, 
Periodicidade AS Periodicidade, 
produtos.estoquemax_produto AS 'Média de venda mensal',
IF(SUM(estoque.Estoque_produto) > produtos.estoquemax_produto * 2, 'Muito alto', IF(SUM(estoque.Estoque_produto) > produtos.estoquemax_produto , 'Alto', IF(SUM(estoque.Estoque_produto) > (produtos.estoquemax_produto / IF(Periodicidade = 'M' , 1 , IF(Periodicidade = 'Q' , 2 , 4))) *0.5, 'Bom', IF(SUM(estoque.Estoque_produto) > (produtos.estoquemax_produto / IF(Periodicidade = 'M' , 1 , IF(Periodicidade = 'Q' , 2 , 4))) * 0.3, 'Baixo', IF(SUM(estoque.Estoque_produto) >  0, 'Crítico', 'Zerado'))))) AS Estado, 
precos.Custo_produto AS Custo, 
produtos.fornecedor_principal AS Fornecedor,
Descricao_produto AS 'Marca/Laboratório', 
grupos_prod.Nome_grupo AS Grupo, 
subgrupos.Nome AS Subgrupo

FROM genius.produtos
JOIN produtos_estoque AS estoque ON produtos.id = estoque.id_produto
JOIN produtos_precos AS precos ON produtos.id = precos.id_produto
JOIN subgruposprodutos AS subgrupos ON produtos.Id_grupo = subgrupos.Id
JOIN grupos_produtos AS grupos_prod ON subgrupos.id_grupo = grupos_prod.Id
WHERE Estado = 'Alto'
GROUP BY Id;
```

Quando eu executo ele me retorna o erro :

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'Estado' in 'where clause'

O problema é que a coluna Estado é dada como resultado dessa parte :

```
IF(SUM(estoque.Estoque_produto) > produtos.estoquemax_produto * 2, 'Muito alto', 
IF(SUM(estoque.Estoque_produto) > produtos.estoquemax_produto , 'Alto',
IF(SUM(estoque.Estoque_produto) > (produtos.estoquemax_produto / 
IF(Periodicidade = 'M' , 1 , IF(Periodicidade = 'Q' , 2 , 4))) *0.5, 'Bom', 
IF(SUM(estoque.Estoque_produto) > (produtos.estoquemax_produto / 
IF(Periodicidade = 'M' , 1 , IF(Periodicidade = 'Q' , 2 , 4))) * 0.3, 'Baixo', 
IF(SUM(estoque.Estoque_produto) >  0, 'Crítico', 'Zerado'))))) AS Estado,
```

ou seja, é resultado de uma formula e não de uma coluna de uma tabela do BD. e o problema só apareceu quando eu usei o:

```
WHERE Estado = 'Alto'
```

Alguém sabe como resolver isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faça um `subselect`, sua coluna *Estado* , ainda não existe dentro do contexto que você esta criando, ou seja ela é a composição da linha.

```
IF(SUM(estoque.Estoque_produto) > produtos.estoquemax_produto * 2, 'Muito alto',
IF(SUM(estoque.Estoque_produto) > produtos.estoquemax_produto , 'Alto', 
IF(SUM(estoque.Estoque_produto) > (produtos.estoquemax_produto / 
IF(Periodicidade = 'M' , 1 , IF(Periodicidade = 'Q' , 2 , 4))) *0.5, 'Bom', 
IF(SUM(estoque.Estoque_produto) > (produtos.estoquemax_produto / 
IF(Periodicidade = 'M' , 1 , IF(Periodicidade = 'Q' , 2 , 4))) * 0.3, 'Baixo', 
IF(SUM(estoque.Estoque_produto) >  0, 'Crítico', 'Zerado'))))) AS Estado,
```

essa (coluna/valor) só existe dentro do seu select, para você acessa-los você tem que criar um `subselect` depois usar em um `where`.

```
select * from 
(
    SELECT produtos.id AS id, 
    nome_produto AS Nome, 
    SUM(estoque.Estoque_produto) AS Estoque, 
    Periodicidade AS Periodicidade, 
    produtos.estoquemax_produto AS 'Média de venda mensal',
    IF(SUM(estoque.Estoque_produto) > produtos.estoquemax_produto * 2, 'Muito alto', IF(SUM(estoque.Estoque_produto) > produtos.estoquemax_produto , 'Alto', IF(SUM(estoque.Estoque_produto) > (produtos.estoquemax_produto / IF(Periodicidade = 'M' , 1 , IF(Periodicidade = 'Q' , 2 , 4))) *0.5, 'Bom', IF(SUM(estoque.Estoque_produto) > (produtos.estoquemax_produto / IF(Periodicidade = 'M' , 1 , IF(Periodicidade = 'Q' , 2 , 4))) * 0.3, 'Baixo', IF(SUM(estoque.Estoque_produto) >  0, 'Crítico', 'Zerado'))))) AS Estado, 
    precos.Custo_produto AS Custo, 
    produtos.fornecedor_principal AS Fornecedor,
    Descricao_produto AS 'Marca/Laboratório', 
    grupos_prod.Nome_grupo AS Grupo, 
    subgrupos.Nome AS Subgrupo

    FROM genius.produtos
    JOIN produtos_estoque AS estoque ON produtos.id = estoque.id_produto
    JOIN produtos_precos AS precos ON produtos.id = precos.id_produto
    JOIN subgruposprodutos AS subgrupos ON produtos.Id_grupo = subgrupos.Id
    JOIN grupos_produtos AS grupos_prod ON subgrupos.id_grupo = grupos_prod.Id
    GROUP BY Id
)d
WHERE d.Estado = 'Alto'
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, era isso mesmo. Só fiquei com uma dúvida, o "d" depois do parenteses não deveria precisar de um AS?

Comment: e dessa forma eu poderia adicionar mais alguns JOIN? por exemplo: JOIN d.id = outra_tabela.id

Comment: você pode usar o AS sem problema, também é possível fazer o JOIN. [tem esse exemplo com algo parecido](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/530381/mysql-correlated-subquery-in-join-syntax)

Comment: Obrigado Goku também ajudou, se precisar de uma força na Genki Dama estamos ai lol kkk

Answer (score 0):

Atribua a cláusula `WHERE` dentro dos testes que você faz antes de atribuir o alias.

acredito que isso funcionara.

Comment: não entendi, vc diz mudar a posição de cláusula para depois da condição IF()?

Comment: Baixo', IF(SUM(estoque.Estoque_produto) >  0, 'Crítico', 'Zerado') where estado = 'alto'))

Comment: Isso não funcionou, o erro passa a ser de sintaxe